# Default selected value of an ng-for generated multi-select in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular8

I need to set default selected values for the multi-select.

I have tried intializing the ngModel to bind the variable and also used `[selected] = "selectedSegment == 'S1'"`. None of them are working for me

```html
<select 
    class="form-control" 
    multiple 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedSegments" 
    name="segment_select"
    (change)="onChangeSegment()"
>
    <option *ngFor="let segment of segmentsToDisplay; let segIndex = index;" [ngValue]="segment">{{ segMap[segment] }}</option>
</select>
```

Just need the first item on the list as the default selected value.

Comment: selectedSegments is an Array of strings and segmentsToDisplay has two items 'S1' and 'S2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set your ngModel to the default value.

Suppose segmentsToDisplay has elements = ['s1', 's2', 's3' ];

then your ngModel Should be selectedSegments= ['s1'];

Comment: I tried with code, it works fine. https://next.plnkr.co/edit/z8M5hhEq3x49x9tZ . Check and let me know. How you are setting ngModel value ?

Comment: Thanks Man it worked, I had to initialize in more than one place. Thanks a lot.

Comment: great, Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have

```
segmentsTodisplay = [0, 1, 2];
segMap = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

it's quite straightforward just set

```
selectedSegments = [0, 2];
```

Then 'a', 'c' will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selected attribute on index, but using ['selected' as value](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp):

```
<option [selected]="segIndex === 0 ? 'selected' : null "></option>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this - Angular reactive forms default selected value Set

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {FormGroup,FormArray,FormControl,FormBuilder,Validators, NgForm } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  blogForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  Technology: any[] = [
    { ID: "1", Name: "Angular" },
    { ID: "2", Name: "Html" },
    { ID: "3", Name: "Nodejs" },
    { ID: "4", Name: "React" }
  ];

  DefaultSelectedArray: any[] = [
    { ID: "1", Name: "Angular" },
    { ID: "3", Name: "Nodejs" }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isBuildForm();
    this.setDefaultValues();
  }

  setDefaultValues() {
    let valueArray = [];
    this.DefaultSelectedArray.forEach(element => {
      valueArray.push(element.ID);
    });
    this.blogForm.controls.Name.setValue(valueArray);
  }

  isBuildForm() {
    this.blogForm = this.fb.group({
      Name: ["", Validators.required]
    });
  }
}





<form [formGroup]="blogForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(blogForm.value)" novalidate="novalidate" autocomplete="off">
    <select multiple class="form-control"  formControlName="Name">
       <option *ngFor="let option of Technology; let i = index" [value]="Technology[i].ID" [text]="Technology[i].Name" >
                {{ Technology[i].Name }}
        </option>
  </select>

</form>

<pre>{{blogForm.value| json}}</pre>
```

[image: Result - selected value]